# create a PHP multidimensional array in laravel 5.4 for the mysql join statement which which return multiple row for a user id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

I have a jobs table, which has a job id and some other stuff

### jobs

id job_title       job_profile
1  software engg   java developer

and another table could be job location table

### job_location

id  city      job_id
1   Delhi        1
2   Mumbai       1

Here job_location.job_id is the jobs.id

Now I want to fetch a job consisting of all the possible city.

I tried

```
$job_ids = DB::table('jobs');
$job_ids->where ('jobs.id', $id);
$job_ids->join('job_location', 'jobs.id', '=', 'job_location.job_id');

$job_ids = $job_ids->get();
```

Now its giving me two object of jobs, one for each cities.
Output:

```
[{"id":1,"job_title":"Job Title Software Developer","job_profile":"Associate Software Developer","city":"Delhi"},{"id":1,"job_title":"Job Title Software Developer","job_profile":"Associate Software Developer","city":"Mumbai"}]
```

Expected Result:

```
[{"id":1,"job_title":"Job Title Software Developer","job_profile":"Associate Software Developer","city":{"Delhi","Mumbai"}}]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**Note: I am using laravel query builder**

Comment: Join will return alway one record (but with only one city), or more records, as you have now. You can use eloqent relationship (wich means 2 selects "in the backend"), 2 manual selects or select in select.

Comment: I am new to laravel. Can you please explain a bit?

Answer (score 0):

That's how an SQL join works for a one to many relationship: it will return a joined row for your jobs table on top of every row it matches with. It's probably easiest to just have a separate search where you search for all job_locations that have job ids that exist in the jobs table and then combine the results